# Fetching Logged in User Info for display

Tags: go, go-iris

I am using https://github.com/kataras/iris Go web framework. I have:

1. User Registered
2. User Verified & Logged in
3. Session created and set with key `username` with user (table & struct) `username`

Now, here is my code for logged in user:

```
// Loaded All DB and other required value above

allRoutes := app.Party("/", logThisMiddleware, authCheck) {
    allRoutes.Get("/", func(ctx context.Context) {
        ctx.View("index.html");
    });
}
```

In authcheck middleware

```
func authcheck(ctx context.Context) {
    // Loaded session.
    // Fetched Session key "isLoggedIn"
    // If isLoggedIn == "no" or "" (empty)
    // Redirected to login page
    // else
    ctx.Next()
}
```

My Session function

```
func connectSess() *sessions.Sessions {
    // Creating Gorilla SecureCookie Session
    // returning session
}
```

Now, my problem is, how do I share Logged User value to all routes in template. My Current option is:

```
// Loaded all DB and required value
allRoutes := app.Party("/", logThisMiddleware, authCheck) {

    allRoutes.Get("/", func(ctx context.Context) {
        // Load Session again
        // Fetch username stored in session
        // Run Query against DB
        // Share the user struct value.
        // Example ctx.ViewData("user", user)
        ctx.View("index.html");
    });

    allRoutes.Get("dashboard", func(ctx context.Context) {
        // Load Session again
        // Fetch username stored in session
        // Run Query against DB
        // Share the user struct value.
        // Example ctx.ViewData("user", user)
        ctx.View("index.html");
    });
}
```

But problem with above code is, I will have to write session for each route and run query again for each route I run and than share.

I feel, there must be better way of doing it , rather than loading session twice for each route one in `authCheck` middleware and second inside `allRoutes.Get` route.

I need ideas on how this can be optimised and user data can be shared to template by just writing code one time and not repeating below for each route

```
        // Load Session again
        // Fetch username stored in session
        // Run Query against DB
        // Share the user struct value.
        // Example ctx.ViewData("user", user)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's easy you can use the `ctx.Values().Set/Get` to make something shareable between your route's handlers or middleware(s).

```
// load session manager once
sess := connectSess()

func authCheck(ctx context.Context) {
    session := sess.Start(ctx)
    // Load your user here.
    // [...]
    // Save the returning user to the local storage of this handlers chain, once. 
    ctx.Values().Set("user", user) // <-- IMPORTANT
}

app.Get("/", func(ctx context.Context) {
    // Get the user from our handlers chain's local storage.
    user := ctx.Values().Get("user") // <-- IMPORTANT

    // Bind the "{{.user}}" to the user instance.
    ctx.ViewData("user", user)
    // Render the template file.
    ctx.View("index.html")
})

app.Get("dashboard", func(ctx context.Context) {
    // The same, get the user from the local storage...
    user := ctx.Values().Get("user") // <-- IMPORTANT

    ctx.ViewData("user", user)
    ctx.View("index.html")
})
```

**That's all, pretty simple, right?**

But I have some **notes for you**, read them if you have more time.

When you're on root "/" you don't have to create a party for it(`.Party`) in order to add middlewares (begin(`Use`) or finish(`Done`)), use just the `iris.Application` instance, `app.Use/Done`.

Don't write this:

```
allRoutes := app.Party("/", logThisMiddleware, authCheck) {

    allRoutes.Get("/", myHandler)
}
```

Do that instead:

```
app.Use(logThisMiddleware, authCheck)
app.Get("/", myHandler)
```

It's easier to **read and understand**.

I've **also** noticed that you're using `;` at the end of your functions, your editor and `gocode` tool will remove those, when you write a program using the Go Programming Language you shouldn't do that, remove all `;`.

Last, please read the documentation and the examples, we have many of them at https://github.com/kataras/iris/tree/master/_examples , hopes you the best!

Comment: Wow! That was easy! Also is there any harm in using `Party` as my intention was to differentiate between `user route` with `allRoutes` and `admin routes` with `adminRoutes`. Is there any performance issue using it like that ?

Comment: I have used `app.Use` to share default title, host, layout file and settings table data.  Do you recommend avoiding `app.Party`? if so, please let me know, why!

Comment: No John, it's not harmful neither any performance cost, if you'd like `Party` for root routes then continue with that, what ever you like more!!