# Type interface {} is interface with no methods

Tags: go

I am using https://github.com/kataras/iris golang web framework. This is follow up mail from the last question asked here - [Fetching Logged in User Info for display - Golang Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130446/fetching-logged-in-user-info-for-display-golang-template)

I am finally using code that was mentioned in the previous post like:-

`ctx.Values().Get("user")`

and the value that user is set or has is "Struct" type:-

```
// users is struct below

var user users

// details are fetched from DB and assigned to user 
// like mentioned here http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html 
// Now value is set
ctx.Values().Set("user", user);
```

But after getting the value, When I use in different handler and print:-

```
user := ctx.Values().Get("user")
fmt.Println(user.ID)
```

I get the error:-

`user.ID undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)`

I need help in "Type assertion" for the interface. How can I "type assert" above value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang type interface {} is interface with no methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277884/golang-type-interface-is-interface-with-no-methods)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) does just that, asserts a value is a given *type*.

```
userID := user.(users).ID
```

Use they type name, and it should work.